# In cavity optomechanics, what does it mean that a cavity mode is driven by a classical field?

Tags: optics, quantum-optics, cavity-qed

What do we mean by the statement when we say that a cavity mode is driven by a classical field or classically controlled field, in Cavity Optomechanics?

Answer (score 1):

It means that one or multiple channel modes (an external mode in the [Jaynes-Cummings Model](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Jaynes%E2%80%93Cummings_model) of CQED) of the cavity are driven by a [coherent state](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Coherent_states#Coherent_states_in_quantum_optics). Here "driven by a coherent state" is to be understood within the [Input-Output formalism](https://journals.aps.org/pra/abstract/10.1103/PhysRevA.31.3761): The input operator is in a coherent state.

It turns out that for a coherent state the quantum stochastic equations of motion can be replaced by an effective Hamiltonian that is equivalent to a classical driving field Hamiltonian.